# Wamp wont use Apache but IIS instead ?

Tags: apache, iis-7.5, wamp

I just installed the WAMP service [The wamp page](http://www.wampserver.com)

The problem I am having is that, when I try running the local host, or the `phpmyadmin` it runs it automatically with my IIS7 server. I did stooped the IIS server from running, but then it says that the page it could not be found?
How to I prevent the IIS from starting on the start up, since I don't really use it?
How do I make the Apache my default server or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each port only one server can listen to incoming requests. Http uses port 80 by default and it seems like IIS is configured to listen on that port on your machine.

To change this you have to edit the binding settings of iis (in "Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager" -> click on Sites\"Default Web Site", then there should be a link "Bindings" on the right side of the screen). In apache you have to edit on of the config files: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/mpm_common.html#listen and restart apache.

You can reach your other webserver (not listening on port 80) by explicitly specifying the port number in the address: e.g. http://localhost:85/phpmyadmin

Comment: Hey thanx for your feedback. I stoped IIS and then try to test **port 80** with apache and then it seems that it is this Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 that is also running on port 80? _ISS_ was installed in my machine with the .NET and **Microsoft visual basic express**, so I'm not really sure how many services were installed at that time. And i expected the ISS to run only when i run the visual basic.